# connect mysql using c++ and [ERROR] unresolved external symbol _mysql_error@4 referenced in function _main

Tags: c++, mysql, database

I have a segment C++ code to connect database MySQL

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <mysql.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
MYSQL *conn;
MYSQL_RES *res;
MYSQL_ROW row;

const char *server = "localhost";
const char *user = "root";
const char *password = "";
const char *database = "girl";
const int port = 3307;
conn = mysql_init(NULL);

if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server, user, password, database, port, NULL, 0)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "\s\n", mysql_error(conn));
}
return 0;
}
```

errors were occurred :Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _mysql_error@4 referenced in function _main
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _mysql_init@4 referenced in function _main
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _mysql_real_connect@32 referenced in function _main

help me ! thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Try #include "winsock.h" before #include "mysql.h". And also make sure that you copy libmysql.dll file in the Debug folder of your Project.

Comment: Thanks @shamsun. I surprise for your answer.This question was posted when I was studying at the university